# SSIS Script Component Error when using foreach loop on row

Tags: c#, ssis

I have the following Script Components that makes all data in a specific column Title Case.
In addition to that I would like to format certain address suffixes by converting them to upper case. How ever I get the following error when I add the `foreach` loop:

> Error: 0xC0202009 at Data Flow Task, SQL Server Destination [302]:
>   SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".*

I have reduce the timeout setting on the destination task flow and reduce the `MaxCommitSize` but nothing seem to work. When I remove the loop, the process works.

Code:

```
public static string StringInput(string input)
{
    TextInfo tCase = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
    return tCase.ToTitleCase(Regex.Replace(input.ToLower(), @"\s+", " "));
}

public static List<string> AddressSuffix = new List<string>();

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{

    AddressSuffix.Add("Sw");
    AddressSuffix.Add("Nw");
    AddressSuffix.Add("Ne");
    AddressSuffix.Add("Se");

    if (!Row.STREET1_IsNull)
    {
        foreach (string suffix in AddressSuffix)
        {
            if (StringInput(Row.STREET1) == suffix)
            {
                Row.STREET1 = StringInput(Row.STREET1).ToUpper();
            }
            else
            {
                Row.STREET1 = StringInput(Row.STREET1);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you certain that the above code is resulting in the supplied error? This code simply changes the value in the current row. The supplied error is generated from a destination component

Comment: I am not sure, however if I remove the `foreach`, the the task works, I am able to use all other parts of the code without errors. Just not sure what else to do.

Comment: So what do you *think* your code is doing? It smells like you're trying to standardize the appearance of an address but I think you have a few logic errors in there.